# Setting n-th subobject based on array of keys

Tags: javascript

I have object `pivot`, that has multiple accessors of different depths.

For keys array `const keys = ['rotation']` I want my code to assign value `x` like this:

```
pivot['rotation'] = x
```

And for array `const keys = ['rotation', 'y']` I want the code to do this:

```
pivot['rotation']['y'] = x
```

Solution I tried looks like this:

```
accessors.forEach(a => accessor = accessor[a])
accessor = x
```

However, after logging the `accessor` value, I found out it's just primitive value of `0.1`, instead of an object reference.

Can I get the object reference somehow? Or do I need to go a different path to achieve this?

Working code would also be something ugly like next example, which is not acceptable.

```
if (accessors.length == 1) {
    pivot[accessors[0]] = x
} else if (accessors.length == 2) {
    pivot[accessors[0]][accessors[1]] = x
}
```

Comment: https://youmightnotneed.com/lodash#set this might help get an idea

Comment: This is the correct answer. The one by Nina also looks like it should work, but it invokes an error within babylonjs. Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it? @cmgchess

Comment: btw what error you get. if this works it has to be something fixable with the below answer as well.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '_isDirty' on number '0.2'`. In the first iteration of the loop the value is set to `0.1`, then 2nd to `0.2`, so this occurs in the second iteration. And it's coming from `t2.computeWorldMatrix` function of `transformNode`, so I'm not going into it right now as you helped me with the solution.

Comment: hmm looks like a babylon specific thing i have no clue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is something similar to [lodash `set`](https://youmightnotneed.com/lodash#set). keep in mind this mutates the object

```js
const pivot = {}

const set = (obj, path, value) => {
  // Regex explained: https://regexr.com/58j0k
  const pathArray = Array.isArray(path) ? path : path.match(/([^[.\]])+/g)
  const pathLength = pathArray.length;
  pathArray.reduce((acc, key, i) => {
    if (acc[key] === undefined) acc[key] = {}
    if (i === pathLength - 1) acc[key] = value
    return acc[key]
  }, obj)
}
set(pivot, ['rotation', 'x'], 'y');

console.log(pivot);
```

since your path is already an array you don't need the regex part

```js
const pivot = {}
const set = (obj, path, value) => {
  const pathLength = path.length;
  path.reduce((acc, key, i) => {
    if (acc[key] === undefined) acc[key] = {}
    if (i === pathLength - 1) acc[key] = value
    return acc[key]
  }, obj)
}

set(pivot, ['rotation', 'x'], 'y');

console.log(pivot);
```

Answer (score 2):

You couldd reduce the array of keys and preserve the last key as accessor for assigning the value.

```js
const
    setValue = (reference, keys, value) => {
        const last = keys.pop();
        keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k] ??= {}, reference)[last] = value;
    },
    pivot = {};

setValue(pivot, ['rotation', 'x'], 'y');

console.log(pivot);
```

Comment: Great approach, but my interpretation of what the OP asked for with `pivot['rotation']['y'] = x` was an output object in this format: `{ rotation: { y: 'x-value'; } }`. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah something like lodash set

Comment: I'm sorry if I was confusing. `x` is just a primitive number, like `5`. `accessors` array is telling how deep to go into `pivot` children, while the last element of `accessors` array should be assigned a value of `x`.

Comment: it could take any length of the array of keys.